# iterate, Nonetype converting to String

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

I am Scraping Financial Data from "http://profit.ndtv.com/stock/hindustan-unilever-ltd_hindunilvr/financials-historical"

Code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "http://profit.ndtv.com/stock/hindustan-unilever-ltd_hindunilvr/financials-historical"


page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table", {"id": "finsummaryTab"})
tr = table.findAll("tr")


def periodEnding(index):
    td = BeautifulSoup(str(tr[2]), 'html.parser')
    td_list = td.find_all("td")
    return td_list[index].getText()

b = print(periodEnding(1))
a = str(b)
print(type(a))
for i in a:
    print(i)
```

Output :

```
216.35

<class 'str'>
N
o
n
e
```

I dont know why this happens, can anybody help me with this.
thannkyou
I want to iterate this numbers

Comment: Why are you even re-parsing the table row *again*? `td_list = tr[2].find_all('td')` would give you the same results without a whole conversion to string and back to BeautifulSoup `Tag` objects.

Comment: Also, don't use the `python-2.7` tag when you are using Python 3. You'd have gotten a syntax error in Python 2 with this exact code.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, 
I want to post data into MySQL database. and the result of  "td_list = tr[2].find_all('td')" ***** is *****  "[<td>Share Capital
            </td>, <td class="txt-right">216.35
            </td>, <td class="txt-right">216.27
            </td>, <td class="txt-right">216.25
            </td>, <td class="txt-right">216.15
            </td>, <td class="txt-right">215.95
            </td>]"

Comment: Yes, and so is the result of `BeautifulSoup(str(tr[2]), 'html.parser').find_all('td')`. So why convert to a string then back to a BeautifulSoup object again? That's just extra work for your computer that makes *no sense*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Thankyou ..... I got It

I want to know my people unlike this question!??

Comment: I don't know, I did not vote. I can't read minds, I'm afraid.

Comment: haha... My script runs properly now

Comment: Glad it does! Was my answer of any assistance at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the return value of `print()`:

```
b = print(periodEnding(1))
```

`print()` **always** returns `None`. You then tried to print each individual character of the string `"None"` (produced by `a = str(b)`), so you indeed get the letters `N`, `o`, `n` and `e` printed.

Store the return value of `periodEnding()` instead:

```
b = periodEnding(1)
print(b)
```

You are also needlessly reparsing the `tr[2]` object here:

```
td = BeautifulSoup(str(tr[2]), 'html.parser')
td_list = td.find_all("td")
```

There is **no point** in doing this. `tr[2]` is a `Tag` object and supports `find_all` directly:

```
def periodEnding(index):
    td_list = tr[2].find_all("td")
    return td_list[index].getText()
```

This gives you the exact same result without converting a whole subtree to a string then back again into virtually the same BeautifulSoup object tree.